# return boost::smatch and get substring "\000"

Tags: c++, boost

here is my code, I get messy code if I extract boost::regex_search into function #match

```
boost::smatch match() {
    std::string s = "foobar";
    std::string re_s = "f(oo)(b)ar";
    boost::regex re(re_s);
    boost::smatch what;
    if (boost::regex_search(s, what, re)) {
        return what;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    boost::smatch what = match();
    std::cout << what.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << what[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << what[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << what[2] << std::endl;
    return (0);
};
```

the output is:

```
3
\000\000\000\000\000
\000\000
\000
```

how to make `what[n]` return real string

Comment: If you have C++11 it's time to move to std::regex.

Answer (score 2):

`boost::smatch` contains `string::iterator` values for tracking the matches internally. You are matching against a `string` object that is on the stack. When the `match()` function returns, that string is destructed and the iterators become invalid. Try moving the string `s` to the `main()` function and passing it into `match()` as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

In Boost, the `operator[](int index)` of `smatch` returns a `const_reference` which is a typedef for `sub_match<BidirectionalIterator>`. `sub_match<BidirectionalIterator>` has a cast operator to a string, but you must cast the match to a string, otherwise it calls the `operator<<(basic_ostream,sub_match)` function which returns the distance from the last match. If you cast the `what[0]` to a `std::string`, it will print out. (I tested it on my machine.)

This is the code I used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

boost::smatch match() {
    std::string s = "foobar";
    std::string re_s = "f(oo)(b)ar";
    boost::regex re(re_s);
    boost::smatch what;
    if (boost::regex_search(s, what, re)) {
        return what;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    boost::smatch what = match();
    std::cout << what.size() << std::endl;
    std::string what0 = what[0];
    std::cout << what0 << std::endl;
    std::cout << what[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << what[2] << std::endl;
    return (0);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If only wanna use regex, use std::regex_search instead of boost::regex_search is good, following work well.

```
#include "boost/regex.hpp"
#include "iostream"
#include "regex"

std::smatch match() {
    std::string s = "foobar";
    std::string re_s = "f(oo)(b)ar";
    std::regex re(re_s);
    std::smatch what;
    if (std::regex_search(s, what, re)) {
        return what;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::smatch what = match();
    std::cout << what.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << what[0].str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << what[1].str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << what[2].str() << std::endl;
    return (0);
};
```